# should I "conda update conda" if I installed using brew?

Tags: conda, homebrew

I'm using homebrew on macOS with apple silicon. I installed homebrew into my home directory, not /opt/Homebrew or whatever, because I'm doing everything from a standard (non-admin) user account without sudo.

The installation of conda was fine; I just did `brew install --cask miniconda`. However, when I did `conda update conda`, it said a bunch of the packages that base conda needs are outdated, and asked if I wanted to update.

I thought about it, and this is somewhat confusing; if I do `brew upgrade --cask miniconda`, it says "no updates needed", since I just installed it like 2 minutes ago. **But what would happen if I proceeded with `conda update conda`? There would be a bunch of updates that `conda` made which `brew` probably doesn't know about. Would that be safe or would it lead to undefined unintended behavior / state?**

Note that I have not created any envs yet, I assume  `conda update conda` is independent of what conda env I'm in.

Comment: my guess is that since `conda update conda` only works if I'm in the (base) conda environment, that means it's only mutating stuff in the (base) environment, and not the part installed by brew. But even so, that would mean the part in the (base) env is newer than the part installed by `brew install --cask miniconda`, which is still confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you’ve installed a Conda *distribution*, it should be self-managed. I would not use homebrew to manage it further. And yes, keep Conda updated with

```
conda update -n base conda
```

Note the specification of the environment. That is, `conda update` commands apply to the active environment, unless an environment is explicitly specified. The `conda` package itself is installed in the **base** environment.